# Liferay Custom fields on User object

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have created three custom fields on user object. Those fields are listed on "**Custom Fields**" under "**Miscellaneous**" section. 
[image]

I need those fields on "**Details**" under "**User Information**" section.
[image]

Some one can help me how fix that issue I need those fields in "**Details**" section.

Comment: I'd suggest to ask on the Liferay Forums. For Stackoverflow you should add what you've already tried and what problems you got into. It doesn't sound like you tried something already - rather would like to have a full solution for your problem. Thus it's not a good fit for the format of *this* site (stackoverflow). It could even be that the documentation on https://dev.liferay.com has a chapter on almost exactly this problem, but definitely on all the techniques you need to use.

Comment: You could achieve this using hook by overriding details jsp to include Custom fields and remove Custom fields jsp section

Comment: @Pankajkumar Kathiriya,Can you please the share document for related that issue.

Comment: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/customizing-jsps-by-extending-the-original

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a both a jsp hook to add the field, and a BaseStrutsPortlet for that portlet. your liferay hook will resemble this

```
<hook>
    <language-properties>
        content/Language_es.properties
    </language-properties>

    <custom-jsp-dir>/custom_jsps</custom-jsp-dir>
    <struts-action>
        <struts-action-path>/my_account/edit_user</struts-action-path>
        <struts-action-impl>
            org.yourpackage.hook.UpdateUserInfoHook
        </struts-action-impl>
    </struts-action>


</hook>
```

then on your custom_jsps you should replace the original with

/custom_jsps/html/portlet/users_admin/user/details.jsp

I recomend you get the original file from liferay source code.

Once you got your field in your jsp inside your UpdateUserInfoHook you have to extend BaseStrutsPortletAction

```
   public class UpdateUserInfoHook extends BaseStrutsPortletAction {
```

Hope this helps.